# Sudden change in performance after shipping computer

Tags: windows-10, memory, graphics-card, cpu, performance

I have recently shipped my computer domestically and have received it, but it is performing terribly. I have been trying to run Watch Dogs (which only a few weeks ago it was able to run fine), but now I can't get past the Ubisoft logo. I checked Task Manager and the processes seem to be fine (6% CPU and 19% Memory at idle) I believe it may be a problem with the graphics card but not really sure how to tell for sure. It seem to boot fine at first, but after trying to run Watch Dogs it has very sluggish performance. I have attached a photo of a wire that must have come loose when it was shipped, but I believe this wire is from the optical drive (which I am not worried about), however it could be from the GPU.

I've checked under dxdiag and under Display -> Device it shows my processor: Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000 but not my GPU. However under Display adapters it shows my CPU and GPU (NVIDIA GeForce GTX970). I have tried opening the NVIDIA Control Panel and it says `You are not currently using a display attached to a NVIDIA GPU.`

*Specs:*
 8GB of Ram
 i5-2500K CPU @ 3.3GHz
 GTX 970

**UPDATE: I unplugged the GPU and found this wire loose behind it. Could this be the cause?, Otherwise it could've been the connection for the loose wire but, That connection had far less pins than this one.**

[UPDATE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIOAL.jpg)

Comment: It sounds like the GPU may be loose (hopefully not damaged), so the integrated Intel graphics are being used. Have you tried taking out the graphics card and then reseating it? (taking all the usual care to avoid static damage, not touching anything gold plated etc.)

Comment: I checked and realised I didn't have the monitor plugged into the gpu which I have now changed it has significantly improved but still I am waiting at a load screen 5 minutes later

Comment: re:update image - that is a header for your front panel audio.  Note that the cable has two connectors, one of which is plugged in (but hidden) in your photo.

Comment: Can you suggest how I can check if the card is damaged?

Answer (score 0):

The hint to resolve your problem is in your question.  Try connecting the display cable to the discrete graphics card instead of the port on the motherboard which is driven by the on-board graphics chip.  Many on-board graphics accelerators will automatically disable when a discrete graphics card is detected (or even if there is no display plugged in).

Comment: I just connected the display to the gpu but still there seems to be huge delays I have been waiting at a load screen for 5 or so minutes.

Comment: Ok, well, to address your concern about the wire in the picture, that might be ok and you've just never noticed it before.  It's a PCI-E power connector and some of them are 6 pins and some are 8 pins.  Many power supplies will come with 8 pin cables that will work as 6 pin connectors with the 2 remaining hanging off the side as seen in the picture.  If there is no spot for the remaining 2 pins on the connector on the graphics card then it's fine.

Comment: As for poor performance after moving a PC, it's likely something isn't seated correctly, and since it's not crashing, only slowing down, I would suspect that the issue is related to thermal throttling.  Check that the CPU fan is making good contact with the CPU.  It's retaining clip should be securely fastened.  Check that the CPU fan (or all fans, actually) is even spinning while it's powered on.  Perhaps the power cable for a fan somehow was disconnected during transport.

Comment: Jason Brockdorf if you look at the first photo at the end of the GPU there is a two prong connector on the GPU. I seem to have found the connector on the other side of the computer, I thin it was just powering the light on the fans. System is still just as sluggish

Comment: I have noticed the GPU fans initially spin when booting up but then stop. Is this normal?

Comment: That is not normal, even for the latest/most efficient cards.  GTX 970 fans should always be spinning, especially while using any application which works the GPU.

Comment: Ok, so what could be causing this, A loose connection?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54550/discussion-between-jason-brockdorf-and-t-kearsley).

Comment: @JasonBrockdorf my new gtx 1070 most certainly stops its fans when not under stress... This is a built in feature.  Granted, it isn't standard on most cards, and you would expect them to spin when gaming.